# SQL variable into diffrent column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to show a set of string into new column based on some columns value.

I tried to use isnull (name, variable = ''null) but does not work

```
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @TEL VARCHAR (MAX)

SET @NAME = '- inNAME '
SET @TEL = '- inTEL '

SELECT IIF(NAME IS NULL, @NAME = '- notinNAME'), IIF(TEL IS NULL, @TEL = '- notinTEL;), (@NAME+ @TEL)  AS RESULT FROM ADDRESS

NAME    TEL    RESULT
NULL    07     - notinNAME - inTEL
ARK     NULL   - inNAME - notinTEL
ARK    07      - inNAME - inTEL
NULL   NULL    - notinNAME - notinTEL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
SELECT CONCAT(CASE WHEN NAME IS NULL THEN '- notinNAME' ELSE '' END,
              CASE WHEN TEL IS NULL THEN '- notinTEL' ELSE '' END
             )
FROM ADDRESS;
```

You cannot use variables for a few reasons.  First, SQL Server does not allow you to assign variables in a `SELECT` and also to return values.

More importantly, SQL (in general) does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `SELECT`.  Your formulation assumes a particular order of evaluation, so it is not going to work.

EDIT:

If you want to use the variables:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CASE WHEN NAME IS NULL THEN @NAME ELSE '' END,
              CASE WHEN TEL IS NULL THEN @TEL ELSE '' END
             )
FROM ADDRESS;
```

Comment: I believe you can use variables inside the CASE.

Comment: so , no way I cant make it possible :( apologies. I am new in sql.